# Regular expression does not match "0.00" value

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression, been tested on regex101.com
The expression matches values "30,413.83" and "65,464.70" **BUT** it does not match "0.00" value, if I add one more digit to the left of the decimal point, it matches. F.I. If I change the "0.00" value to "40.00", it matches all 3 values

How can I change my regex to match all 3 values?

Regex:

```
["]*\d+[,]*\d+\.\d{2}["]*(?=,)
```

String:

```
1650028985,02/01/2018,301217 MUNDO DEL JUGUETE KENN,2344112341191,"30,413.83","0.00","65,464.70",301217 MUNDO DEL JUGUETE KENN SANTO DOMI DO 000082368555,0,
```

Comment: Try `'~"*\d+(?:,\d+)?\.\d{2}"*(?=,)~'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are targetting only the double-quoted float values with a limit of two decimal places.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3supOS/1/

Pattern: `~"\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}"~`

This requires:

- double quote wrapping
- at least 1 digit before the decimal point
- a comma for a thousands separator if/where appropriate
- a decimal point
- two digit decimal value

If you are "extracting" rather than "validating", the pattern can be written more simply and still be effective.

---

Your pattern:

```
["]*    #optional zero or infinite double quotes
\d+     #required one or more digits
[,]*    #optional zero or infinite commas
\d+     #required one or more digits
\.      #required one dot
\d{2}   #required two digits
["]*    #optional zero or infinite double quotes
(?=,)   #required match must be trailed by a comma
```

Comment: If this is not what you want, please clarify the task.